# When I run project on local system it throws "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer"

Tags: spring, scala, wicket

I am facing such issue more than 1 week. It compiles but when I hit any url it throws "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer" on browser window. My teammate use the mac system and its works on mac but not work on Ubuntu.
and cglib-3.3.0.jar file is already included.
If any one have suggestion. Please comment your answer.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Please post your stacktrace as text instead of as a screenshot. Please also post the dependencies from your pom.xml if your are using maven.

Comment: I am using build.sbt file for dependency manage.

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer
 at org.apache.wicket.proxy.LazyInitProxyFactory.createProxy(LazyInitProxyFactory.java:182)
 at org.apache.wicket.spring.injection.annot.AnnotProxyFieldValueFactory.getFieldValue(AnnotProxyFieldValueFactory.java:166)
 at org.apache.wicket.injection.Injector.inject(Injector.java:111)
 at org.apache.wicket.spring.injection.annot.SpringComponentInjector.inject(SpringComponentInjector.java:124)

Comment: I am using latest spring version "5.4.5" and that version transitively add the cglib-3.3.0.jar file. @KajHejer If you know  the what exact issue i am facing.

Comment: There is no Spring 5.4.5. 5.3.5 is the latest one. Please update your question with the content of your build.sbt file! Also please paste the full stack trace!

Comment: "org.springframework.security" % "spring-security-ldap" % spring_version,                                                                 "org.springframework.security" % "spring-security-oauth2-client" % spring_version,                                                                                                   
"org.springframework.security" % "spring-security-oauth2-jose" % spring_version,                                                                                                            and spring version is "5.4.5' only that three spring dependency we are using in our project

Comment: also spring boot starter "2.4.4" is used in our project